# ERROR: Could not build wheels for nnunet, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python

How to fix this problem? I try to install NNUNet model, but this error stop me to do that.

I have installed pyproject.toml already, but it still can't work. I deleted my environment and created it again, but the problem still exist

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [444 lines of output]
      C:\Users\chris\anaconda3\envs\nnunet\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:498: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: Invalid dash-separated options
      !!

              ********************************************************************************
              Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future
              versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead.

              This deprecation is overdue, please update your project and remove deprecated
              calls to avoid build errors in the future.

              See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html for details.
              ********************************************************************************

      !!
```

Comment: I think you might want [`nnunetv2`](https://github.com/MIC-DKFZ/nnUNet/blob/master/documentation/installation_instructions.md).

Comment: what command did you use to install?